# How to make linear reveal animation instead of circular reveal animation in Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, animation, android-animation, circularreveal

I want to animate my button that reveal from left offset of button to right of that. What I want is linear reveal animation instead of circular reveal animation.
Please help me. Thanks.

**Update**

I want two method that show and hide view based on linear reveal animation.

Comment: What have you tried to make this linear reveal work?

Answer (score 1):

try below code for linear reveal effect -

```
public class ViewAnimationUtils {

public static AnimatorSet createLinearReveal(final View viewToReveal, final int offsetWidth, final int offsetHeight, final int duration) {
    viewToReveal.clearAnimation();

    final int targetWidth = viewToReveal.getMeasuredWidth();
    final int targetHeight = viewToReveal.getMeasuredHeight();

    viewToReveal.getLayoutParams().height = offsetHeight;
    viewToReveal.requestLayout();

    final ValueAnimator heightAnimator = ValueAnimator
            .ofInt(offsetHeight, targetHeight)
            .setDuration(duration);
    heightAnimator.addUpdateListener(animation -> {
        viewToReveal.getLayoutParams().height = (int) animation.getAnimatedValue();
        viewToReveal.requestLayout();
    });

    final ValueAnimator widthAnimator = ValueAnimator
            .ofInt(offsetWidth, targetWidth)
            .setDuration(duration);
    widthAnimator.addUpdateListener(animation -> {
        viewToReveal.getLayoutParams().width = (int) animation.getAnimatedValue();
        viewToReveal.requestLayout();
    });

    final AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
    set.playSequentially(widthAnimator, heightAnimator);
    set.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
    return set;
}
```

}

after adding this class just pass your view to animate and offset values to the createLinearReveal method.

Comment: thanks for answer but your solution create ripple effect on button and not reveal.

Comment: The source of this code seems to be: https://medium.com/@arekk/linear-reveal-animation-a0ee1aafc81f